# Trouble with changing checkbox states on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, scope

I'm developing a game to test some properties of control codes. The based-game is this well-known magic one: you have some cards with numbers and select all cards which a number of your choice appears. Then, the "magician" can discover your number using binary code of cards you have selected. A very simple version is as follows:

card 1 (represents bit xx1 if selected)

- 1
- 3
- 5
- 7

card 2 (bit x1x)

- 2
- 3
- 6
- 7

card 3 (bit 1xx)

- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7

In example, if you are thinking on number 3, you'll select cards 1 and 2, that represents (011) in binary, that's number 3.

Well, this explanation is to put you in context. My version of the game have additionally a layer of verification cards and numbers. You can find the actual code **[in this codepen](https://codepen.io/estemon/pen/zdLgEj)**. It's full of alerts to give me info about variables. If you run it you'll find first execution is ok, but next tries it starts to being crazy.

I have some troubles with check/uncheck checkboxes with jQuery. I've tried many solutions and read documentation and other related posts, but nothing appears to solve this issue. I think there's some troubles with the scope of the `$lie` var. When I click button, it's supossed to `$lie = ''`; and after another function `$lie` gets a new value. This is correct, but when I pass `$lie` to this function it remembers previous value.

I'm copying here the complete skeleton of the functions that works with or are related to `$lie` var:

```
var $lie = '';
function check() {
    $lie = ''; // only to clear on successive calls
    if (something) {
        // $lie gets its correct value here
    }
    return $lie; //I have made some alerts here and it is working well always
}

function lying() {
    if ($lie === something) {
         // something related with "something"
    }
}

function message($lie) {
    // other stuff
    $(some-div).on('click', function() {
        // more stuff
        $change = $('#' + $lie); // here $lie gets the first value, but not reset on successive tries, that is why program goes crazy
        $change.prop('checked', function(i, i2) {
            return !i2;
        });
    });
}

$(run-button).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    check();
    if ($lie !== '') { // do only if $lie have value
        lying();
        message($lie)
    }
}
```

First time I execute the program `$lie` have a correct value and works properly. But next runs the `$lie` value is not reset and remember the previous value. I'm not sure where is the mistake, I've tried to reset `$lie = '';` in many places, but ever is handling the first value to the `message($lie);` function.

Thanks for your help and your suggestions and excuse me if the answer is in other post and I've not seen it!

Comment: each time you call the `message()` function you're binding an additional click handler to `some-div`

Comment: thanks @billyonecan! then, how can I prevent to click handler on the message() function? I understand what you are saying. Even more, I've redesigned the entire program because I was before with problems on nested 'click' handlers. But it's doesn't solved, as you pointed.

Comment: If you're binding too much you can either make sure you're binding once by unbinding before binding `.off('click').on('click')` or better yet [using a delegated event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) outside of the message function.

Comment: @estemon you don't need the function wrapper for the `some-div` click handler, just trigger it directly inside of `run-button`'s click handler: `$(some-div).trigger('click');` (you don't need to supply `$lie` since it's defined in the global scope)

Comment: @Johannes I've tried what you suggested, `.off('click')` and it works. I'll learn about delegated events, however, to improve it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @billyonecan thanks for suggest, I'll learn how the `.trigger('click')` works and try to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment seemed to help answer the question at hand, here it is as an expanded answer.

In JQuery there are a few ways to handle event binding.

`$(some-div).on('click', function() {});`
The code above is the one you are using, and it means that every time you call this code, it will select every element that exists on the page that matches the selector.

In your code since this is inside of a function there's a good chance you'll end up re-binding already bound events. This causes duplicate events and really makes a mess.

You can mitigate this by modifying the code a bit:

`$(some-div).off('click').on('click', function() {});`

This code makes sure that all the click events are removed, before any are added, stopping duplicate events.

However, if your goal is to simply make sure the valid elements are always bound, regardless of whether they exist on initial page load or not, then delegated events are your friend. The good news is, it's not much different or difficult to do.

Simply write your code a bit different like so:

`$('.parent').on('click', '.child', function() {});`

In this case `.parent` is a selector that encompasses where all your events will be (which in your case I believe is your `.container`. `.child` in this case would be equivalent to your `some-div` selector.

With this kind of event binding you don't need to worry about unbinding and rebinding or duplicate events as it will automatically manage this for you based on the content on the page.